# opening random extensions with notepad

Tags: malware

I get files with random extensions sometimes in order to bypass corporate firewalls. Usually I would just ask the other party what it is that I just received. Other times I get curious and open the file with notepad. Sometimes the file would have a plain text header which describes how to open it. Could this potentially cause "issues" if I didn't do it in a sandbox?

Comment: To see what to open such a file with, I use the `file` command (You know how many people believe they can turn a Word doc file to pdf by renaming it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, someone might be able to find a buffer overflow in notepad that could cause issues when opening a file, but the chances are pretty minimal and the file would have to be specifically made to exploit notepad.  A sandbox is still technically the safest, but I generally view files in Total Commander's viewer (which is equivalent to opening it in notepad) because the risk is so low that it isn't really a problem unless you have really high security needs.

Answer (score 0):

As another user said, the only way they could possibly affect you is by finding an exploit in notepad itself. This would most likely be a buffer overflow attack since the only time notpad seems to have any issues is when opening files that are larger than the PAGEFILE + RAM combined. Other exploits may exist but notepad has been around forever...its probably pretty tight.

However, a more major issue would be opening the files in a third party note editor like [Notepad++](http://notepadplusplus.org) as these editors may have unknown attack vectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this on a regular basis create a script that outputs the first line of the file. This will prevent any issues involving exploits targeted for notepad.

Here's an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130116/windows-batch-commands-to-read-first-line-from-text-file